# How can I modify and test javascript source code for a project which uses minified javascript code in production?

Tags: javascript, node.js, minify

I'm working on a project which uses js source files from multiple directories and compiles them into a common dist/ directory which is used in production. One way I can test my changes to the js code would be to make the changes into the source code and reinstall the entire project to generate the new dist/ directory. Is there an easier and more practical way to do this?

Comment: If you are using `grunt` for example you could create a development task which uses the resources provided in the src directory.

Comment: @KRONWALLED the project uses webpack, I may have to run a webpack script to generate the minified files

Answer (score 0):

As I like my production and development environments to be (mostly) equal I use source maps for this issue. This is the way I usually build by js:

1. JS Hint
2. Generate Source maps
3. Concat JS into one file
4. Uglify
   I do this by using gulp and some plugins. Those shouldn't be hard to find.

The benefits of this aproach are:

- Serving a small js file
- no difference between dev and prod
- readable JS source for debugging
- no redeploy needed